# How to toggle a Boolean field in an Array element in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, positional-operator

Consider this data

```
{ 
    "_id" : ..., 
    "array" : [
        { "name" : "value1","flag" : true } ,
        { "name" : "value2","flag" : false }
  ]
}
```

I would like to toggle the 2nd array element (from false to true)

I know I can update a specific element using the very useful $ positional operator like this:

```
db.myCollection.update(
    {'array.name':'value2'},
    {
        $set: {
            'array.$.flag':true
        }
    },false,true);
```

But is there a way to use the $ positional operator also for the value setting?

e.g. like this?

```
db.myCollection.update(
    {'array.name':'value2'},
    {
        $set: {
            'array.$.flag':'!array.$.flag' //<--
        }
    },false,true);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not possible at the moment. MongoDB doesn't allow expressions in updates that depend on fields in the document. You'll have to get and set in two separate operations.

However, there's a trick to make it in one operation (and therefore atomic). Instead of a boolean value, have an integer. Then even values will represent `false`, odd ones - `true`.

```
// get documents with false flag
db.collection.find({flag: {$mod: [2, 0]}})

// get documents with true flag
db.collection.find({flag: {$mod: [2, 1]}})

// toggle flag
db.collection.update(query, {$inc: {flag: 1}});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it is so, so it means, it's not going to be transactional, right?

Comment: @EranMedan: yeah, but there's a workaround. See updated answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev hi what do you think of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76090104/13583510)