# How to toggle the boolean value in array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to toggle the boolean value which is in the array of the schema.
I am trying to toggle the value with the value present in the database(refer the code). But it is just turning true to false, but not false to true.

**Following is the code**

```
exports.postStatusItemchange = (req, res, next) => {
  const productId = req.body.productId;
  const itemId = req.body.itemId;
  
  Product.updateOne({_id: productId, "items._id": itemId}, {
    $set: {
      "items.$.status": !"items.$.status"
    }
  }).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    res.send("done");
  }).catch(err => {
    res.send(err);
  })
}
```

**Following is the schema for the reference**

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  status: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: true,
  },
  items: [
    {
      foodName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      },
      status: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
      }
    },
  ],
});
```

I am expecting that the value in the status field gets toggle whenever the API is ran. Thank you for your time.

Comment: i think u will have to go for something hectic like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vlfaFOWNbqk).

Comment: I agree with @cmgchess. Please post it as an answer

Comment: @nimrodserok i dont know why positional operators cannot be used with this

Comment: do you want all in one query. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506878/how-to-toggle-a-boolean-field-in-an-array-element-in-mongodb) is a method with multiple queries

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, the positional operators won't be much of help in this case and you will have to go for something hectic with `map`. This has its disadvantages since it has to loop over every item in the items array. Also, note that I'm using `[{$set:{...}}]` that's because from [Mongo 4.2 onwards you can aggregation pipeline inside update](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```js
Product.updateOne({_id: productId}, 
[
  {
    $set: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "i",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: [ "$$i._id", itemId ] },
              { $mergeObjects: [ "$$i", { status: { $not: "$$i.status" } } ] },
              "$$i"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
)
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vlfaFOWNbqk)

[This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vN-JHDn7f6m) is what I meant. You need to pass an explicit value if you are going to use `$set` with positional operators. Otherwise, even if you write a condition it will update the field with the whatever condition object passed.